# WPF MVVM: Approach to chose for dynamic selection of UserControl to display object acording to its type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my application, I need to manage (CRUD) the subject and the collection of different activities on this subject, represented by different classes, who are direct or indirect children of common activity class.

For this subject, I want to create the ViewModel, who also contains the сollection of ViewModels of activities.

For instance, like advanced package tracking with common information about receiver, sender and so on, and different heterogenous actions like received in post office(country, code) , sent by refrigerator (temperature data, time, driver, etc), cleaned by customs (fee, officer).

So, for represent this collection, I need a different UI controls (I think to use UserControls) loaded dynamically to the container of the view.

And my question is about which is the industrial and common way to associate an activity to its UI control, using MVVM

Comment: That is what DataTemplates were made for. Declare DataTemplate resources which have their DataType property set to the view model type they are supposed to visualize. Then assign an instance of a particular view model to a ContentControl or have it as element of the ItemsSource of an ItemsControl, and the appropriate DataTemplate will be chosen automatically. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Your DataTemplates may of course contain declarations of your own UserControls. Avoid the very common mistake to explicitly set the DataContext of your UserControls. Although you will find this "advice" in many blog posts, it is wrong because it breaks the way data binding is supposed to work in WPF.

Comment: Thank you, Clemens. I see your answer only like a comment, unfortunately, but it is the solution and answer

Comment: I have voted to close the question because I think it is too broad, i.e. not about a specific programming problem. I may be wrong however...

Comment: We don't know enough to give a good answer imo. Could be that these things overlap so an itemscontrol wouldn't be a good approach. Type might not be an ideal driver so a datatemplateselector might be more appropriate. Nested controls might be an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you would design the UI for a subject with some sort of items control (`ItemsControl`, `ListView`, ...) and provide type-dependent `DataTemplate` per concrete activity viewmodel type. This `DataTemplate` can be implemented by displaying some usercontrol or doing anything else.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}">
  <ItemsControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CleaningActivityViewModel}">
      <uc:CleaningActivityUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HappyGoLuckyActivityViewModel}">
      <uc:HappyGoLuckyUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

In this code sample `vm` is the `xmlns` declaration for the viewmodel namespace and `uc` is the `xmlns` declaration for the usercontrol namespace.

There is a lot of room for usecase-dependent variation from this approach. The ItemsControl can be customized (eg. setting `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`) or replaced by a different items host. If `DataType` is not applicable in all cases to decide the correct UI, an `ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector` might be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for correcting TargetType to DataType ;)

Comment: And adding `{x:Type ...}` which is required here.

Comment: @Clemens wow, I should really go back to implementing answers in VS instead of writing them directly to the browser^^

Comment: And run the program. It would have successfully compiled without x:Type, but would not have worked.